# Typesafe variadic function

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates, c++17

I want to write a function that accepts a variable number of string literals.  If I was writing in C, I would have to write something like:

```
void foo(const char *first, ...);
```

and then the call would look like:

```
foo( "hello", "world", (const char*)NULL );
```

It feels like it ought to be possible to do better in C++.  The best I have come up with is:

```
template <typename... Args>
void foo(const char* first, Args... args) {
    foo(first);
    foo(args);
}

void foo(const char* first) { /* Do actual work */ }
```

Called as:

```
foo("hello", "world");
```

But I fear that the recursive nature, and the fact that we don't do any type checking until we get to a single argument, is going to make errors confusing if somebody calls `foo("bad", "argument", "next", 42)`.  What I *want* to write, is something like:

```
void foo(const char* args...) {
    for (const char* arg : args) {
        // Real work
    }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Edit: There is also the option of `void fn(std::initializer_list<const char *> args)`, but that makes the call be `foo({"hello", "world"});` which I want to avoid.

Comment: Are you tied to the call syntax `foo("hello", "world");`? If not, then a `std::initializer_list<const char *>` is an appropriate parameter type

Comment: Doesn't this trigger the [parameter packs not expanded with '…'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33868486/parameter-packs-not-expanded-with)?

Comment: @gsamaras My desired syntax doesn't work at all.  If `T args...` meant "`std::initializer_list<T>` initialized from all remaining arguments, then no.

Comment: @Caleth - I've updated the question: I want to avoid ({}) (but thanks for clarifying my requirements)

Comment: Re: "fear that [it's] going to make errors confusing" -- try it.

Comment: This isn't really answering the question, but the simplest way to do this might be to pass a `std::vector<std::string>` rather than messing with variadic args

Comment: Only string-literals, or anything implicitly convertible to `const char*`?

Comment: @Deduplicator - in my *specific* case, anything convertible to `const char *`.  The only time I can see you would want to distinguish between that and a string literal, is when you want to depend on the static lifetime of the literal - but there's no way for the type system to distinguish `const char foo[] = "bad";` (with automatic lifetime) from `"good"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While all other answers solve the problem, you could also do the following:

```
namespace detail
{
    void foo(std::initializer_list<const char*> strings);
}

template<typename... Types>
void foo(const Types... strings)
{
    detail::foo({strings...});
}
```

This approach seems (at least to me) to be more readable than using SFINAE and works with C++11. Moreover, it allows you to move implementation of `foo` to a `cpp` file, which might be useful too.

Edit: at least with GCC 8.1, my approach seems to produce better error message when called with non `const char*` arguments:

```
foo("a", "b", 42, "c");
```

This implementation compiles with:

```
test.cpp: In instantiation of ‘void foo_1(const ArgTypes ...) [with ArgTypes = {const char*, int, const char*, const char*}]’:
test.cpp:17:29:   required from here
test.cpp:12:16: error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘const char*’ [-fpermissive]
 detail::foo({strings...});
 ~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

While SFINAE-based (liliscent's implementation) produces:

```
test2.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test2.cpp:14:29: error: no matching function for call to ‘foo(const char [6], const char [6], int)’
     foo("hello", "world", 42);
                         ^
test2.cpp:7:6: note: candidate: ‘template<class ... Args, typename std::enable_if<(is_same_v<const char*, Args> && ...), int>::type <anonymous> > void foo(Args ...)’
 void foo(Args... args ){
  ^~~
test2.cpp:7:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
test2.cpp:6:73: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘struct std::enable_if<false, int>’
     std::enable_if_t<(std::is_same_v<const char*, Args> && ...), int> = 0>
```

Answer (score 15):

I think you probably want something like this:

```
template<class... Args,
    std::enable_if_t<(std::is_same_v<const char*, Args> && ...), int> = 0>
void foo(Args... args ){
    for (const char* arg : {args...}) {
        std::cout << arg << "\n";
    }
}

int main() {
    foo("hello", "world");
}
```

Comment: This is quite heavy for what it achieves... Not to say complete abuse of `enable_if` vs specifying the type of the arguments.

Comment: @rubenvb How do you specify variadic number of arguments of a same type ? I don't understand what you mean by "abuse".

Comment: See my answer and also @Nevin's.

Comment: @Deduplicator Then use `std::is_convertible_v`. It's not clear whether they want implicit conversion. It's even not clear whether they want just a hard error or SFINAE. That's why my answer starts with *I think you probably want something like this*

Answer (score 8):

Note:  it is not possible to match just string literals.  The closest you can come is to match a `const char` array.

To do the type checking, use a function template which takes `const char` arrays.

To loop over them with range-based `for`, we need to convert it to an `initializer_list<const char*>`. We can do so directly with braces in the range-based `for` statement, because arrays will decay to pointers.

Here is what the function template looks like (note:  this works on zero or more string literals.  If you want one or more, change the function signature to take at least one parameter.):

```
template<size_t N>
using cstring_literal_type = const char (&)[N];

template<size_t... Ns>
void foo(cstring_literal_type<Ns>... args)
{
    for (const char* arg : {args...})
    {
        // Real work
    }
}
```

Comment: very nice... a little suggestion: add an example of your solution over the "What I want to write, is something like" code in the question.

Comment: @max66, I updated the code and explanation to use range-based for, as per the OP request for syntax.

Answer (score 2):

+1 for the C++17 liliscent's solution.

For a C++11 solution, a possible way is create a type traits to make an "and" of multiple values (something similar to `std::conjunction` that, unfortunately, is available only starting from C++17... when you can use folding and you don't need `std::conjunction` anymore (thanks liliscent)).

```
template <bool ... Bs>
struct multAnd;

template <>
struct multAnd<> : public std::true_type
 { };

template <bool ... Bs>
struct multAnd<true, Bs...> : public multAnd<Bs...>
 { };

template <bool ... Bs>
struct multAnd<false, Bs...> : public std::false_type
 { };
```

so `foo()` can be written as

```
template <typename ... Args>
typename std::enable_if<
      multAnd<std::is_same<char const *, Args>::value ...>::value>::type
   foo (Args ... args )
 {
    for (const char* arg : {args...}) {
        std::cout << arg << "\n";
    }
 }
```

Using C++14, `multAnd()` can be written as a `constexpr` function

```
template <bool ... Bs>
constexpr bool multAnd ()
 {
   using unused = bool[];

   bool ret { true };

   (void)unused { true, ret &= Bs ... };

   return ret;
 }
```

so `foo()` become

```
template <typename ... Args>
std::enable_if_t<multAnd<std::is_same<char const *, Args>::value ...>()>
   foo (Args ... args )
 {
    for (const char* arg : {args...}) {
        std::cout << arg << "\n";
    }
 }
```

**--- EDIT ---**

Jarod42 (thanks!) suggest a far better way to develop a `multAnd`; something as

```
template <typename T, T ...>
struct int_sequence
 { };

template <bool ... Bs>
struct all_of : public std::is_same<int_sequence<bool, true, Bs...>,
                                    int_sequence<bool, Bs..., true>>
 { };
```

Starting from C++14 can be used `std::integer_sequence` instead of it's imitation (`int_sequence`).

Comment: Upvoted. It's worth mentioning that this is actually an implementation of `std::conjunction` in C++17.

Comment: @liliscent - `std::conjunction`! I was remembering that there is something similar but the name doesn't come in my mind. Thanks.

Comment: `multAnd` can be implemented that way too: `template <bool...> struct Bools{}; template <bool... Bs> struct all_of : std::is_same<Bools<true, Bs...>, Bools<Bs..., true>> {};`

Comment: @Jarod42 - I don't know how I didn't think about it: the `std::is_same` check over the shifted list is one of my preferred tricks. Thanks.

Comment: It's somewhat unnatural to disallow all implicit conversion.

Answer (score 1):

Using [C++17 fold expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) on the comma operator, you can simply do the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

template<typename OneType>
void foo_(OneType&& one)
{
    std::cout << one;
}

template<typename... ArgTypes>
void foo(ArgTypes&&... arguments)
{
    (foo_(std::forward<ArgTypes>(arguments)), ...);
}

int main()
{
    foo(42, 43., "Hello", std::string("Bla"));
}
```

[Live demo here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ea29bdab2f6298c7). Note I used `foo_` inside the template, because I couldn't be bothered to write out 4 overloads.

---

If you really really really want to restrict this to string literals, change the function signature as Nevin's answer suggests:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

template<std::size_t N>
using string_literal = const char(&)[N];

template<std::size_t N>
void foo(string_literal<N> literal)
{
    std::cout << literal;
}

template<std::size_t... Ns>
void foo(string_literal<Ns>... arguments)
{
    (foo(arguments), ...);
}

int main()
{
    foo("Hello", "Bla", "haha");
}
```

[Live demo here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b3a6c45c8cdbd83a).

Note this is extremely close to the C++11 syntax to achieve the exact same thing. See e.g. [this question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17339789/256138).

Comment: You just removed the `enable_if`. And your answer doesn't answer the question, the question specifically wants a `for` loop.

Comment: My code works as if a for loop was written, minus the temporary copies of the arguments in an  initializer_list.

Comment: Your first version addresses heterogeneous types, which cannot be written into a `for` loop. Your second version are also heterogeneous, not to mention that OP wants `const char*`. I wouldn't say that's bad, but your criticism of my code with a downvote is going too far.

Comment: @liliscent I don't specifically want a for loop - that's just what I wrote in the example.  Sorry for the lack of clarity.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the nearest you can get to a function accepting any arbitrary number of `const char*` but nothing else uses a template-function and forwarding:

```
void foo_impl(std::initializer_list<const char*> args)
{
    ...
}

template <class... ARGS>
auto foo(ARGS&&... args)
-> foo_impl({std::forward<ARGS>(args)...})
{
    foo_impl({std::forward<ARGS>(args)...});
}
```

The subtlety is in allowing the normal implicit conversions.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<type_traits>
#include<iostream>

auto function = [](auto... cstrings) {
    static_assert((std::is_same_v<decltype(cstrings), const char*> && ...));
    for (const char* string: {cstrings...}) {
        std::cout << string << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(){    
    const char b[]= "b2";
    const char* d = "d4";
    function("a1", b, "c3", d);
    //function(a, "b", "c",42); // ERROR
}
```

Answer (score 0):

And now... for something completely different...

You can write a type wrapper struct as follows

```
template <typename, typename T>
struct wrp
 { using type = T; };

template <typename U, typename T>
using wrp_t = typename wrp<U, T>::type;
```

and a `foo()` function receiving a variadic list of `char const *` simply become

```
template <typename ... Args>
void foo (wrp_t<Args, char const *> ... args)
 {
   for ( char const * arg : {args...} )
      std::cout << "- " << arg << std::endl;
 }
```

The problem is that you can't call it as you want

```
foo("hello", "world");
```

because the compiler isn't able to deduce the `Args...` types.

Obviously you can explicit a list of dummy types

```
 foo<void, void>("hello", "world");
```

but I understand that is a horrible solution.

Anyway, if you accept to pass through a trivial template function

```
template <typename ... Args>
void bar (Args ... args)
 { foo<Args...>(args...); }
```

you can call

```
bar("hello", "world");
```

The following is a full C++11 working example

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename, typename T>
struct wrp
 { using type = T; };

template <typename U, typename T>
using wrp_t = typename wrp<U, T>::type;

template <typename ... Args>
void foo (wrp_t<Args, char const *> ... args)
 {
   for ( char const * arg : {args...} )
      std::cout << "- " << arg << std::endl;
 }

template <typename ... Args>
void bar (Args ... args)
 { foo<Args...>(args...); }

int main ()
 {
   bar("hello", "world"); // compile

   // bar("hello", "world", 0);  // compilation error
 }
```

Answer (score -2):

Of course it is possible, this compiles and runs what you want (pay attention)

```
#include<iostream>
                                                                                          template<class... Char>
                                                                                          // hehe, here is the secret      
auto foo(const Char*... args )                                                            ->decltype((char const*)(*std::begin({args...})), (char const*)(*std::end({args...})), void(0))
{
    for (const char* arg : {args...}) {
        std::cout << arg << "\n";
    }
}

int main() {
    foo("no", "sense","of","humor");
}
```

This is @liliscent solution but with more sugar and, to please @rubenvb, without `enable_if`. 
If you think the extra code as a comment (which is not), **note that you'll see exactly the syntax you are looking for.**

Note that you can only feed an homogeneous list of things that is convertible to `char const*`, which was one of your goals it seems.

Comment: It's not the syntax I was looking for - it has a leading `template <class... Args>`.  I personally find the "humour" of putting the interesting part of the code where it can only be seen with the scroll bar very unfunny.

Comment: No they didn't - but they didn't pretend to.