# C++ template | error: parameter packs not expanded with '...':

Tags: c++, templates, parameters, pack

I'm getting the following error:

```
error: parameter packs not expanded with '...':
  auto const m = msg...;
```

code:

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdarg>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

template<typename... T>
void print(T& ... msg)
{
    auto const m = msg...;
    cout << m;
}

int main()
{
    print("a", "o");
}
```

Comment: What do you expect `auto const m = msg...;` to do?

Comment: You could simply do: `auto m = {msg ...}`.

Answer (score 2):

This syntax:

```
auto const m = msg...;
```

is not valid. Try this:

```cpp
template <typename... T> void print(T &...msg) {
  using var = int[];
  (void)var{0, (std::cout << msg << std::endl, 0)...};
}
```

---

<sup>Thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33868486/parameter-packs-not-expanded-with) reference for being able to answer this question.</sup>

Comment: @max66 amended the answer. Thanks, I learned it.

Comment: Very good, thanks, I asked another question down below

Comment: @Pukki *Why can't I pull it by doing `m[index]`?* – Because `m` is not an array.

Comment: How can I iterate over the arguments?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to save in a variable, and print, only the last value in `msg...` pack, maybe

```
template <typename... T>
void print (T& ... msg)
{
    auto const m = std::get<sizeof...(msg)-1u>(std::tie(msg...));
    std::cout << m;
}
```

If you want to print **all** `msg...` values, starting from C++17 you can use template folding

```
template <typename... T>
void print (T& ... msg)
{ ((std::cout << msg), ...); }
```

Before C++17 you could emulate this using the initialization list of an unused variable (see Rohan Bari's answer for a nice example).

Comment: Thank you, but, can you explain how the variadic works? Why can't I pull it by doing m[index] ?

Comment: @Pukki - It's not simple to explain... anyway, a pack expansion means expansion with a comma between elements. So, if you call `print(1, 2, 3, 4);`, `std::tie(msg...)` become `std::tie(1, 2, 3, 4)`. Template folding (see second example) is more complicated because expand (with an operator as separator, again comma in this example) the full expression; so `((std::cout << msg), ...);` become `std::cout << 1, std::cout << 2, std::cout << 3, std::cout << 4;`. See [this page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) for more details.

Comment: Thank you very much